# Compiling MobileVLCKit with Bitcode on iOS

Tags: ios, libvlc, vlckit

Is there a way to compile VLCKit with bitcode enabled for iOS?

None of the instructions to do this on other forums seem to work - 
I have I only have 'compileAndBuildVLCKit.sh' and when I try and run that I just get an error saying 'xcrun: error: SDK "iphoneos" cannot be located'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, realised that command line location wasn't properly set in Xcode preferences.